# Solution to differential equation with regular singular point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation,
$ \frac{d^2y}{dr^2}-\frac{1}{r}\frac{dy}{dr}+y=0$ , for which $$r=0$$ is a regular singular point. Fuchs' theorem guarantees a solution for such situations. But, I find that for certain boundary condition y(0)=0, y'(0)=1, solution diverges.
Is there a dependence on boundary conditions for an unique solution to this I.V.P? If so, what is the criterion for an unique solution?

Comment: the solution is given by the Bessel function

Comment: After you apply the boundary conditions,one of the constants is zero. The other , goes to infinity.